# Invalid Arguments when fetching data

Tags: flutter

I am using a future builder to display some information on some widgets -

```
  Future _getTaskAsync;

// inside initstate 

    _getTaskAsync = getEventSubtasks(baseURL + getTodoDetailsUrl, widget.taskId);

// outside initstate


     FutureBuilder(
                  future: _getTaskAsync,
                  builder: (context, snapshot){
                    if(snapshot.hasData) {
                      print(snapshot.data);
                      return listViewWidget(snapshot.data);
                    }else{
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                  }),
```

this is the method which fetches the data -

```
Future getEventSubtasks(String url, String taskId) async {
  String id = await secureStore.read(key: "userId");

  String token = await secureStore.read(key: "userToken");
  print("PRINTING USETOKEN FROM GET EVENT SUBTASK = $token");
  print("PRINTING LINK FOR GET EVENT SUBTASKS = $baseURL/todos/find_one_todo_detail");


  var res = await http.post(url, headers: {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "x-access-code" : token}, body: {"todo_card_id" : taskId, "user_id" : id});
  if(res.statusCode != 200){
    loadMore = false;
    loadmoreGroupDetails = false;
    loadMoreGroupScreenTasks = false;
  }

  print("PRINTING GET EVENT SUBTASK RESBODY = ${res.body}");
//print("PRINTING RES BODY RUNTYPE = ${jsonDecode(res.body).runtimeType}");
print("AFTER RUNTYPE FOR GET ONE TODO DETAILS = ${jsonDecode(res.body)}");
  var returnData = jsonDecode(res.body) as Map;

  return returnData;
}
```

Even though i am successfully getting the response body -

```
                      print(snapshot.data);

{
    "error": "0",
    "message": "Got it!",
    "data": {
        "status": "false",
        "_id": "5e4ced2ae8b8a50006ce343c",
        "group_id": "5e4ce9cfe8b8a50006ce3438",
        "date": "2020-02-19T00:00:00.000Z",
        "title": "fdjdbd",
        "priority": 5,
        "description": "eyehe",
        "user_id": "5e37fa0625ba9678443d02ba",
        "tasks": [],
        "created_date": "2020-02-19T08:09:14.264Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

I am getting this error and it points to the FutureBuilder which i have attached in the above code snippet-

```
The following ArgumentError was thrown building Description_Screen(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _Description_ScreenState#88411):
Invalid argument(s)
```

When i completely removed the FutureBuilder widget, I got the same error but this time it was pointing to a navigator.push statement -

```
          List<dynamic> result1 = await Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>
                                    Description_Screen(
                                        data[index].taskName,
//                                      data[index].markComplete,

//                                          data[index].date,
                                        data[index].taskID,
                                        data[index].priority,

                                        data[index].groupID,
//                                          data[index].description,

//                                           data[index].subtasks,
                                        dateToStringtime(setter),
                                      data[index].description
                                    ),
                              )
                          );
```

code for Description screen -

````
class Description_Screen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String taskName;
  final String taskId;
  final int priority;
  final String groupId;
  final String dateValue;
  final String description;

  Description_Screen(
      this.taskName ,
      this.taskId,
      this.priority,
      this.groupId,
      this.dateValue,
      this.description
      );
  @override
  _Description_ScreenState createState() => _Description_ScreenState();
}```

listview widget code -

```
  List<dynamic> subtaskListAPI = [];


listViewWidget(Map<dynamic, dynamic> data) {



  if(data["data"]["tasks"] != null) {
    subtaskListAPI = data["data"]["tasks"];
  }else{
    subtaskListAPI = new List<dynamic>();
  }



  return Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(13),
    child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[

          SizedBox(height: 10,),
          //Todo: remove sized box below and display tasks there
          TextFormField(

            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
//                          initialValue: widget.title,
            validator: (String value) {
              return value.isEmpty ? "task must have a name" : null;
            },
            textAlign: TextAlign.start,
//              maxLength: 100,
            controller: newcontroller, // Just an ordinary TextController
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                value = newcontroller.text;
              });
            },

            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                errorText:
                _validate // Just a boolean value set to false by default
                    ? 'Value Can\'t Be Empty'
                    : null,
                labelText: "name of task"
            ),
            style: TextStyle(height: 1.2, fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black87),
          ),

          TextField(

            controller: descriptioncontroller,
            onEditingComplete: (){
              /// IMPLEMENT ADD DETAIL API CALL HERE
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                icon: Icon(Icons.short_text),
                labelText: "Add details"

            ),

          ),

          SizedBox(height: 10,),

          ListView.builder(  // this listview builder is the only widget which is supposed to use the data fetched from the method

              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: data["data"]["tasks"].length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {


                int dataLength = data["data"]["tasks"].length;

                // ignore: missing_return
                Widget returnTextListTile() {
                  int i = 0;
                  while(i < dataLength){
                    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
//                      refresh();
                    return blackfontstyleMont(
                      text: subtaskListAPI[index]["name"], size: 20,);
                  }
                  i++;

                }

//bool confirmDismiss = false;
                return Container(

                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 40,
                  child: ListTile(

                    title: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24),
                      child: returnTextListTile(),
                    ),
                    trailing: Container(
//color: Colors.black,
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                      child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: (){


                          deleteSubtasks(widget.taskId, subtaskListAPI[index]["_id"]);
                          setState(() {
                            subtaskListAPI.removeAt(index);

                          });
                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                        color: Colors.grey,
                      ),
                    ),

                  ),
                );
              }

          ),
//                      SizedBox(height: 20,),
          SizedBox(height: 10,),

          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          blackfontstyleBebas(text: "Priority", size: 20,),


        ]
    ),
  );
}
```

I have already tried flutter clean and have added a circular indicator widget to the FutureBuilder, Could i get some suggestions on how to fix this error?
````

Comment: In you FutureBuilder you are returning a listViewWidget(snapshot.data) ... I don't see that in your other codes.

Comment: I have added the code for listviewwidget();

Comment: In your listViewWidget(Map<dynamic, dynamic> data) ... make it listViewWidget(snapshot) ... as you're passing snapshot.data from your FutureBuilder ... then inside listViewWIdget() .. access the data from snapshot parameter ... ... as you have found result by `print(snapshot.data)`...it should work

Comment: as in ```   return listViewWidget(snapshot);```? I have tried that but it still gave me the error. Moreover, I have used this same method of declaring futurebuilders on other screens and it works fine over there.